# Как избавиться от ошибки "fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory"?

Tags: gcc, llvm, ubuntu

Я пытаюсь собрать `llvm-gcc` из исходников. При конфигурации пакета с помощью `configure`, в логе появляется ошибка.

*configure:2387: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.*

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что компилятор не может найти библиотеку GMP (GNU Multi-Precision). Если она есть в системе, нужно сказать компилятору, где она. Если ее нет, то установить.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev
```

Comment: Установка библиотек устраняет ошибку.